# next_post_link previous_post_link dont disable when there is no next post, instead loop posts

Tags: wordpress, navigation

```
if(get_adjacent_post(false, '', true)) { 
     previous_post_link('%link','<img src="larr.gif"/>'); 
 }
 else { 
     echo '<img src="larr2.gif"/>'; 
 }; 

 if(get_adjacent_post(false, '', false)) { 
     next_post_link('%link','<img src="rarr.gif"/>'); 
 }
 else { 
     echo '<img src="rarr2.gif">'; 
 };
```

I found this code for showing an image if there is no next post. But what if i like to loop it, i mean if there is no previous or next post just loop at first or end so there whont be a navigation button missing?

Comment: Code looks OK to me, so I'm not sure what you are asking:)

Answer (score 3):

I was just working on a similar issue. I simply combined both the next and previous adjacent post conditions into one if statement... meaning if either a next adjacent post or a previous adjacent post exists, then do something:

```
if ( (get_adjacent_post(false, '', true)) ||  (get_adjacent_post(false, '', false)) ) {
    // Do something if either previous or next post exists
    // You could even nest your original conditionals inside here
} else {
    // If neither exists, then do something different
}
```

I know this is late, but hopefully it helps someone!